# Can a Vec be easily created from a string?

Tags: rust

A `Vec<T>` can be converted to a string:

```
let string: String = format!("{:.?}", vec));
```

Can said string be converted back into a `Vec<T>`?

Comment: You're basically asking if it is possible to parse a string and create a Vec from it. The answer to that is yes, but it is likely not "easy".

Comment: @Herohtar I'm asking if some function exists for this purpose.

Comment: Nothing built in; it's more complex than that. There are, however, parsing crates available.

Comment: If instead of using the default debug output, you use `serde` to convert to JSON and use that as your `Debug::fmt` then parsing it should be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

No, not for generic `T`s, as the output of `Debug` (e.g. via `#[derive(Debug)]`) does not necessarily yield the right format for [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) (if the type even implements it). Furthermore, `Vec` does not implement `FromStr`, so [`parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) needs at least a wrapper around the `Vec`.

Also, while most `Debug` implementation (including the derived one) show the values of their fields, they're not required to. You cannot get the lost information back at that point.